# ros/ros.h No such file or directory

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been running ROS Melodic in my Ubuntu Bionic system. I already had a previous workspace called 'catkin_ws'. Recently, I tried to create another workspace which I named 'ros'. I then created a directory called 'first_package' inside the 'src' folder using the 'catkin_create_pkg' command.
I then coded a small segment which I have attached below and named it hello.cpp inside the 'first_package' which I have attached below.

```
//This is the ROS standard of "hello, world" program//

//This header defined standard ROS classed//
#include<ros/ros.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
//Initialize the ROS system
ros::init(argc, argv, "hello_ros");

//Establish this program as ROS node
ros::NodeHandle nh;

//Send some output as log message
ROS_INFO_STREAM("Hello, ROS!");
}
```

I have changed both the CMakeLists.txt and Package.xml accordingly, but I still receive this error. Could someone please resolve this issue. The error occurs when I use the command 'catkin_make'

This is the CMakeLists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(first_package)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)
catkin_package()
include_directories()
add_executable(hello hello.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hello ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

The package.xml file is as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="2">
  <name>first_package</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>The first_package package</description>
<maintainer email="danish@todo.todo">danish</maintainer>


 <license>TODO</license>
      <buildtool_depend>catkin</buildtool_depend>
      <build_depend>roscpp</build_depend>
      <exec_depend>roscpp</exec_depend>

<export>
  </export>
</package>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312516/ros/ros.h-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2019-01-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> include_directories()
> ```

This is most likely your problem.

Even though you first do this:

> ```
> find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp)
> ```

You never update the include path with the contents of `catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS`, causing the compiler (or actually: the preprocessor) to not be able to find the headers.

You'll need to change that statement to at least something like the following:

```
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Note that this is not really a ROS issue, but a CMake one.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-01-12**:
You solved the issue! Can you be more precise as to why that part was needed to be added inside the include_directories()?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-12**:
See the CMake documentation: [include_directories()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html).

As to why include directories need to be setup, that would be a generic programming question.

As to what `catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS` is: see the general Catkin documentation on ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-12**:
.. the ROS wiki [here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt) and the [Include Paths and Library Paths](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Include_Paths_and_Library_Paths) section in particular.

Use `ctrl+f` and search for `catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS` on that page.

**Comment by [TristanNoctis](https://answers.ros.org/users/39423/tristannoctis/) on 2019-01-12**:
Thanks for that